# How to handle multiple nav panel menus using jquery mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

jquery mobile newbie -- I inherited this project.

I have quite a few 'pages' in my jquery mobile app.  On each page I have a nav panel.  Each page is set up much like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="help_manual" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="panel" id="navpanel_help_manual" data-theme="d" data-display="overlay" data-position="right">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-corners="false">
            <a href="#userPage" data-role="button">Home</a>
            <a href="#MainMenu" data-role="button">User main menu</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <a data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-right" style="margin-top:10px;" href="#navpanel_help_manual"
           data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a> <!-- this is the button that actually brings up the above panel-->

        <h3>User Manual</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        BLAH BLAH CONTENT
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <a href="#MainMenu" data-icon="arrow-l" class="ui-btn-lef ui-btn-inline" data-role="button">Back to main    menu</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This all works well and good.
Then you make another page. ... Then another...  Then another... Suddenly you've got a few dozen pages all with their own 'menus'.  They all work, but there is a LOT of redundant code, given all the menus are identical.

Now I want to make a change to all of the menus.... and instead of modifying one 'navigation panel' I have to make the change a few dozen error-prone times.

I have tried simply taking the 'panel' code and moving it outside the 'page' div... but that results in, effectively, a 'new' 'page' when the button is clicked.  Other attempts at moving the various parts of this code around are similarly broken.

An include could remove the 'list' from the 'core' of the control group... unfortunately, that still leaves a lot of redundant code and I've got one fun tweak:   **This page needs to be able to work offline.**   The purpose of this app is to be able to go offline, collect data 'in the field', and come back and upload it.  So a SSI isn't an good option.

Help?

Comment: You should write your panel once outside the page and as it becomes an external panel you should initialise it manually like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4keLefqf/1/). Is that what you need ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4keLefqf/1/) with multiple pages and the panel written only once.

You should write your panel once outside the page. (If you have one file per page, just write the panel outside the index page as a sibling of the page) :

```
<div data-role="panel" id="navpanel_help_manual" data-theme="d" data-display="overlay" data-position="right">
    ...
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="help_manual" data-theme="d">
    ...
</div>
```

Doing so and as it becomes an [external panel](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external/). You should then initialise it manually.

```
$('#navpanel_help_manual').panel();
```

> The panels below are all located outside the page. Panels outside of a page must be initalized manually and will not be handled by auto init. Panels outside of pages will remain in the DOM (unless manually removed) as long as you use Ajax navigation, and can be opened or closed from any page.